# What is the lifetime of the arguments of FromSql::from_sql?

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I'm using Diesel with Postgres and want to query a `text` field as `*const str`. Diesel has the implementation [`FromSql` for `*const str`](https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/deserialize/trait.FromSql.html#impl-FromSql%3CText%2C%20DB%3E).

The documentation describes:

> The returned pointer is *only* valid for the lifetime to the argument of `from_sql`.

What is the lifetime to the argument of `from_sql`? Is it the same as the lifetime of the connection?

Comment: Trust me, you don't want `*const str`. You rather want a `String`.

Comment: The `from_sql()` method takes an `Option<&DB::RawValue>` as argument. The lifetime of the argument of `from_sql()` is the lifetime of that reference. (I know I'm basically just restating what the documentation already says, but it's unclear to me what exactly the point is you don't understand.)

Comment: @SvenMarnach I agree that that's *probably* what the documentation means, but pedantically (and pedantry matters for raw pointers), the lifetime of the *argument* would be the lifetime of `bytes`, which goes out of scope at the end of the call to `from_sql`. The documentation probably means "the generic lifetime parameter of the argument".

Comment: @hellow Right. I'm using `String`.

Answer (score 1):

`from_sql` will take an `Option<&'a DB::RawValue>` and return a `Result<*const str>`.

Without raw pointers (and with explicit lifetimes), the function definition would be something like:

```
fn from_sql<'a>(bytes: Option<&'a DB::RawValue>) -> Result<&'a str>
```

that the output's lifetime to the input is obvious here and statically checked - but with raw pointers, it's not:

```
fn from_sql<'a>(bytes: Option<&'a DB::RawValue>) -> Result<*const str>
```

the warning is just pointing out that the pointer you get is only guaranteed to be valid for the lifetime of the `&'a DB::RawValue` that you pass into the function. The warning would be unnecessary without raw pointers because the compiler would guarantee that a `&str` only lives as long as whatever it is referencing.

This is `from_sql`'s implementation:

```
fn from_sql(bytes: Option<&DB::RawValue>) -> deserialize::Result<Self> {
    use std::str;
    let string = str::from_utf8(not_none!(bytes))?;
    Ok(string as *const _)
}
```

The reason the ouput's lifetime is dependent on the `bytes` argument is that `str::from_utf8` just performs a UTF-8 validation and does an unsafe cast on `bytes` to an `&str` - you're essentially just returning the input back as a different type. The result of `from_sql` is just a pointer to the same data you passed into it, so that pointer is only valid as long as that input data is valid.